# Trying to form an Elasticsearch query for autocomplete

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I've read a lot and it seems that using EdgeNGrams is a good way to go for implementing an autocomplete feature for search applications. I've already configured the EdgeNGrams in my settings for my index.

```
PUT /bigtestindex
{
  "settings":{
    "analysis":{
      "analyzer":{
        "autocomplete":{
          "type":"custom",
          "tokenizer":"standard",
          "filter":[ "standard", "stop", "kstem", "ngram" ] 
        }
      },
      "filter":{
        "edgengram":{
          "type":"ngram",
          "min_gram":2,
          "max_gram":15
        }
      },
      "highlight": {
      "pre_tags" : ["<em>"],
      "post_tags" : ["</em>"],
        "fields": {
          "title.autocomplete": {
            "number_of_fragments": 1,
            "fragment_size": 250
          }
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So if in my settings I have the EdgeNGram filter configured how do I add that to the search query?

What I have so far is a match query with highlight:

```
GET /bigtestindex/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": {
        "query": "thing and another thing",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags" : ["<em>"],
    "post_tags" : ["</em>"],
    "field": {
      "_source.content": {
        "number_of_fragments": 1,
        "fragment_size": 250
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How would I add autocomplete to the search query using EdgeNGrams configured in the settings for the index?

**UPDATE**
For the mapping, would it be ideal to do something like this:

```
"title": {
        "type": "string",
        "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      },
```

Or do I need to use multi_field type:

```
"title": {
        "type": "multi_field",
        "fields": {
          "title": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "autocomplete": {
            "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
     },
```

I'm using ES 1.4.1 and want to use the title field for autocomplete purposes.... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you need to use it in a field mapping. As in:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "autocomplete": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "standard",
                  "stop",
                  "kstem",
                  "ngram"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "edgengram": {
               "type": "ngram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 15
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "field1": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
               "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

For a bit more discussion, see:

http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams

and

http://blog.qbox.io/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch

Also, I don't think you want the `"highlight"` section in your index definition; that belongs in the query.

**EDIT:** Upon trying out your code, there are a couple of problems with it. One was the highlight issue I already mentioned. Another is that you named your filter `"edgengram"`, even though it is of type `"ngram"` rather than type `"edgeNGram"`, but then you referenced the filter `"ngram"` in your analyzer, which will use the [default ngram filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html), which probably doesn't give you what you want. (*Hint:* you can use [term vectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) to figure out what your analyzer is doing to your documents; you probably want to turn them off in production, though.)

So what you actually want is probably something like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "autocomplete": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "standard",
                  "stop",
                  "kstem",
                  "edgengram_filter"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "edgengram_filter": {
               "type": "edgeNGram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 15
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "content": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
               "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When I indexed these two docs:

```
POST test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"content":"hello world"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"content":"goodbye world"}
```

And ran this query (there was an error in your `"highlight"` block as well; should have said `"fields"` rather than `"field"`)"

```
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "content": {
            "query": "good wor",
            "operator": "and"
         }
      }
   },
   "highlight": {
      "pre_tags": [
         "<em>"
      ],
      "post_tags": [
         "</em>"
      ],
      "fields": {
         "content": {
            "number_of_fragments": 1,
            "fragment_size": 250
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I get back this response, which seems to be what you're looking for, if I understand you correctly:

```
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.2712221,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.2712221,
            "_source": {
               "content": "goodbye world"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "content": [
                  "<em>goodbye</em> <em>world</em>"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to test it out:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/3092992993e0328f7c4ee80e768dd508a0bc053f

Comment: yes - thank you. This helped me understand what I was trying to do!

Comment: is it better to map the autocomplete to the html title or body tag? Trying to be mindful of the size of the index that gets created for the autocomplete

Comment: Depends on your use-case. I could see an argument for either, but I would probably go with title.

Comment: why did you use the "match" query instead of the "match_phrase_query"? I've been reading and it seems like the type of query to use for autocomplete is "match_phrase_query" - just curious... still learning ES - which is amazing!